# Using main(int arc, char *argv[])?

Tags: c, function, pointers, command-line

I have just a couple of questions with this code. Firstly, with the swap function, are we dereferencing ptr1 and ptr2 due to changing the values inside the address, rather than directly swapping the address itself? Secondly, for the main function, how would I set num1 and num2 equal to the input that is given at the command line. For example, "./a.out 5 10" where num1 =5 and num2 = 10. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *ptr1, int *ptr2)
{

  int temp;
  temp = *ptr1;
  *ptr1 = *ptr2;
  *ptr2 = temp;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int num1, num2;
  argv[1] = num1;
  argv[2] = num2;

  printf("%d %d\n", num1, num2);

  swap(&num1, &num2);

  printf("%d %d\n", num1, num2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code snippet  int num1, num2;
  argv[1] = num1;
  argv[2] = num2; does not make sense.

Comment: The `swap` function is swapping the object of the pointers, not the pointers. Even if it did swap the pointers, they would not change on the caller's side (the function arguments are copies). As for trying to set the passed `argv` array to integers: don't. You have been given array of pointers to strings. In any case , `num1` and `num2` have not been initialised.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It probably doesn't make sense because its not correct. Id like to be able to set these variables to whatever the user enters into the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes swap dereference ptr1 and ptr2 to change the value inside the adress, so to get num1 and num2 you should converte argv[1] and argv[2] from string of character to integer and the function atoi will do it here

```
num1 = atoi(argv[1]);
num2 = atoi(argv[2]);
```

Comment: you should include the library #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: you did give it arguments?

Answer (score 3):

Your swap function is correct, the way you get the params from the command line is  not, you want:

```
if (argc == 3) // Never trust the user
{
    num1 = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    num2 = (int)strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s num1 num2\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```